# What kind of spider is this?

Tags: species-identification

[image]

Found in my house in a Beltsville Maryland

Comment: It looks like a brown recluse spider

Comment: @SonicSplasher I strongly disagree. IMO, the only resemblance that spider (in the picture) has with a brown recluse is the abdomen shape. The head, thorax, leg lengths, and overall color doesn't match.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with Trachelas.  Two points stand out for me - the chelicerae are forward-projecting, rather than the flat face of the sac spider; and the rather odd knock-kneed appearance of the front pair of legs is a bit unusual for Trachelas.
There is another two-toned, red-and-tan spider that also turns up in houses in the spring and fall - the European import Dysdera crocata aka the [Woodlouse Hunter](https://bugguide.net/node/view/3388).  That's what this is, I believe.

[image]

Comment: I agree with Dysdera crocata from the generally-longer shape and because of the shape of the chelicerae

Answer (score 1):

I'm 90-95% certain that the spider in question is a *Trachelas tranquillus*, more commonly known as a "Broad-faced Sac Spider".

Broad-faced sac spiders are quite distinct in coloring; they have a dark gray/brown head (cephalothorax) with tan/light-gray abdomen, orange/red legs, and distinct pincers (which can be seen if you look closely). These spiders are also quite common for your area, and aren't a major threat to humans.

---

[image]

[image]

EDIT: I would like to mention that the images I provided (most likely) have enhanced lighting, and/or are much closer to the spider, so the leg color is (expected to be) lighter than what's depicted in your image.